# Combining SMS fragments into the original message

Tags: algorithm, nlp, twilio

We are processing text messages from certain carriers (Sprint) that don't support SMS concatenation. In some cases we get messages that come in random order and I would like to stitch them back together into the original text. The text is different every time obviously but here is a sample message.

Here are the messages in the order we received them

**Was received 1st, should be 3rd - 96 characters**

> needed to perform my job at the highest level possible. I have
>   received 100 on all ABC surveys.

**Was received 2nd, should be 1st - 159 characters**

> I have been in this department as a widget maker since October 2014, I
>   am on the excellent customer service team. I've also received a every
>   quarter that I've

**Was received 3rd, should be 2nd - 157 characters**

> been eligible.  I have also received Top Performer multiple times as
>   well as been in the presidents club 13 times.  I am very proficient in
>   all applications

I would like to re-order these into the original text

> I have been in this department as a widget maker since October 2014, I
>   am on the excellent customer service team. I've also received a every
>   quarter that I've been eligible.  I have also received Top Performer
>   multiple times as well as been in the presidents club 13 times.  I am
>   very proficient in all applications needed to perform my job at the
>   highest level possible. I have received 100 on all ABC surveys.

Does anyone have an idea of how to accomplish this?

Comment: Do you have the whole message including metadata, or only the text?

Comment: The only metadata we have is the time the message was delivered. The delivery timestamps are in not in the correct order either.

Comment: @ShaunBowe wondering where you get this data. Is it sharable?

Comment: The data comes from our clients candidates so unfortunately I can't share it.

Answer (score 4):

In general terms, a naïve approach would be to use a language model to decide which ordering is the most "natural".
I can't provide any code, because you don't give any details of the framework this should work in.

You should use a model trained on a text corpus that is similar to the messages (in terms of vocabulary, spelling, etc.).
Generate all possible orderings and then measure the model's perplexity for each of them.

(Generating all permutations is `O(n!)`, which is more or less the worst case, but for small `n`s (number of SMS fragments) it should be ok.
But if that's an issue, you could build an `n`×`n` matrix of the fragments and use Viterbi's algorithm to find the best path, making incremental look-ups to the language model. You'd have to somehow enforce paths where all fragments occur.)

Answer (score 0):

I took the suggestion from lenz's answer to generate all permutations and attempted to use [Conditional Probabilities from Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/web-language-model/) with little success. That service is still in beta and certainly didn't help with our test messages. The text messages coming in will vary greatly so it seemed unlikely we would be able to create a model and test the possible orderings.

In our particular case we determined that carriers (Sprint) break the message based on spaces and only sends a maximum of 160 characters in each message. Based on that data we generated every possible ordering of a message to see if the carrier would have broke the message in that way. Based on the 3 messages above there are 6 possible orderings of those messages. (below)

**1-2-3**

```
1 -> 2: 96 + " I" = 98. 98 < 160 - Not a valid possibility
2 -> 3: 159 characters + " been" = 164. 164 >= 160 - OK
```

**1-3-2**

```
1 -> 3: 96 characters + " been" = 101.  101 < 160 - Not a valid possibility
3 -> 2: 157 characters + " I" = 159. 159 < 160 - Not a valid possibility
```

**2-1-3**

```
2 -> 1: 159 characters + " needed" = 166. 166 >= 160 - OK
1 -> 3: 96 characters + " been" = 101.  101 < 160 - Not a valid possibility
```

**2-3-1**

```
2 -> 3: 159 characters + " been" = 164. 164 >= 160 - OK
3 -> 1: 157 characters + " needed" = 164. 164 >= 160 - OK
```

**3-2-1**

```
3 -> 2: 157 characters + " I" = 159. 159 < 160 - Not a valid possibility    
2 -> 1: 159 characters + " needed" = 166. 166 >= 160 - OK`
```

**3-1-2**

```
3 -> 1: 157 characters + " needed" = 164. 164 >= 160 - OK 
1 -> 2: 96 + " I" = 98. 98 < 160 - Not a valid possibility
```

You can see from the above calculations that the only valid combination is 2-3-1. The other combinations would have broken up differently. In cases where we have 1 possibility we use that as the "answer".

If we had scenarios that had more than 1 possibility we used some weighting algorithms based on capitalization and punctuation to find best fit. If we still could not determine the answer after that we took the highest weighted result in the order the messages were received (They come in the right order most of the time).

Comment: So assuming 1,2 and 3 are the messages which should be in that position. I submitted each message to the grammar checker at textgears.com which returned the highest score for 1. I then submitted 1+2 and 1+3 and it scored 1+2 highest. I also tried 2+3 and 3+2 and it scored 2+3 highest. No idea if they are a good provider, it was just the first one I clicked, but there seemed to be a lot of grammar/sentence checking api services to choose from which might be suitable for what you want

Comment: I'll definitely give them a shot. Thanks.